# Lspline and bs produce very different coefficients for linear splines - which is preferred?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, splines

In the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lspline/vignettes/lspline.html) for the `lspline` package in `R` it says that the package computes

> Linear splines with convenient parametrisations such that:
>
> - coefficients are slopes of consecutive segments
> - coefficients capture slope change at consecutive knots

This is straightforward. However, the regression coefficients for both options differ from the results of the `bs` function in `splines` despite setting `degree = 1`.

| **Spline function** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Lspline (consecutive)** |  |  | 0.201 |
| xlin_con1 | 0.17 | 0.02, 0.93 |  |
| xlin_con2 | 1.50 | 0.79, 2.88 |  |
| xlin_con3 | 1.13 | 0.48, 2.65 |  |
| xlin_con4 | 0.88 | 0.35, 2.16 |  |
| xlin_con5 | 0.91 | 0.47, 1.77 |  |
| xlin_con6 | 0.47 | 0.14, 1.42 |  |
| **Lspline (marginal)** |  |  | 0.201 |
| xlin_mar1 | 0.17 | 0.02, 0.93 |  |
| xlin_mar2 | 8.74 | 1.07, 88.7 |  |
| xlin_mar3 | 0.75 | 0.19, 2.89 |  |
| xlin_mar4 | 0.78 | 0.16, 3.81 |  |
| xlin_mar5 | 1.04 | 0.26, 4.19 |  |
| xlin_mar6 | 0.52 | 0.10, 2.46 |  |
| **Bspline** |  |  | 0.201 |
| xbsplin1 | 0.14 | 0.02, 0.92 |  |
| xbsplin2 | 0.22 | 0.03, 1.13 |  |
| xbsplin3 | 0.23 | 0.03, 1.28 |  |
| xbsplin4 | 0.22 | 0.03, 1.17 |  |
| xbsplin5 | 0.20 | 0.03, 1.12 |  |
| xbsplin6 | 0.05 | 0.00, 0.58 |  |

What does `bs` convey, and which function is preferable for a regression table?

**Reproducible example**

```
#Packages used
library(lspline)
library(splines)
library(gtsummary)

#Generate data
set.seed(123)
y <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace = T)
x <- rnorm(1000)

#Spline functions (k = 5, uniform from p5 to p95)
xlin_con <- lspline::qlspline(x, q = seq(0.05, 0.95, length.out = 5))
xlin_mar <- lspline::qlspline(x, q = seq(0.05, 0.95, length.out = 5), marginal = T)
xbsplin <- splines::bs(x, knots = quantile(x, probs = seq(0.05, 0.95, length.out = 5)),
                       degree = 1)

#All knots are in the same place
identical(attr(xlin_con, "knots"), attr(xlin_mar, "knots"), attr(xbsplin, "knots"))
## [1] TRUE

#Fit splines
mod1 <- glm(y ~  xlin_con, family = binomial())
mod2 <- glm(y ~ xlin_mar, family = binomial())
mod3 <- glm(y ~ xbsplin, family = binomial())

#All models give same predictions
all.equal(fitted(mod1), fitted(mod2), fitted(mod3))
##[1] TRUE

#Table
print(as_kable(tbl_stack(list(tbl_regression(mod1, exponentiate = T,
               pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3),
               label = list(xlin_con ~ "Lspline (consecutive)"))%>%
  add_global_p(quiet = T) %>%
    bold_labels() %>%
    modify_header(label = "**Spline function**"),
tbl_regression(mod2, exponentiate = T,
               pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3),
               label = list(xlin_mar ~ "Lspline (marginal)")) %>%
  add_global_p(quiet = T) %>%
  bold_labels(),
tbl_regression(mod3, exponentiate = T,
               pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3),
               label = list(xbsplin ~ "Bspline")) %>%
  add_global_p(quiet = T) %>%
  bold_labels()), quiet = T)))
```

Comment: Coefficients are irrelevant, because different bases exist even for the same spline.  What matters is the *fit.*

Comment: @whuber but isn't the fit equivalent across the three options in the provided example?

Comment: Frankly, I don't care to read through your code to try to figure out the answer to that question.  The three equal p-values suggest your three splines are yielding identical fits and that's all that matters.   Your underlying question concerns which form of a spline might be "better." That answer depends on why you are using splines and how you are specifying their characteristics (such as numbers of knots).

Comment: No problem @whuber. I am using splines to relax the linearity assumption in logistic regression for a survey analysis on healthcare utilisation data. K = 5 placed uniformly from the 5th to 95th percentile. I decided on linear splines vs e.g., cubic splines for easier interpretation.

Comment: You might find that not to be an improvement.  Splines are difficult to interpret, even linear splines.  The best solution I have found is to plot the fit (conditional on holding values of all other variables fixed near their means).  That will *show* your audience what the spline is doing.  It will also reveal how much it might improve over not using a spline at all.

Comment: @whuber potentially stupid question, but would the plot you suggest look more like A or B here for a linear spline? https://ibb.co/1RLC4bT

Same model object, ````Effect```` vs ```predictorEffect``` from the ```effects``` package

Comment: Not a stupid question.  (B) is a linear spline.  It's not necessarily worse than (A)--that depends on the nature of the response and your objectives.  For instance, sometimes I choose such crude-looking representations to impress on the audience that there's substantial uncertainty in the fit.